# afterFind() seems to be running one extra time, with incorrect $primary value

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a model called ShippingBatch which hasMany Order. Order is a key model which in-turn has relationships with many other models

I am trying to make a $this->recursive = 2 read() call on a ShippingBatch, such that I get the Orders and also Order's relationships. I am also running an afterFind() to populate some calculated values.This causes a bit of a loop, as the Order part of the result also have ShippingBatch information.

Its not too much of a problem as the $primary==false check in the afterFind cuts off the problems.

But, in one case, the afterFind is running one extra time than it should, with a seemingly incorrect value of $primary (= true).

Can anyone point me to something that might be wrong?

Comment: It's difficult to comment without seeing the code. Could you post the relevant code here.

Comment: Perhaps using Containable would help you sort out what data you want returned? This way you could cut out the ShippingBatch from the Orders. Unless you need to know which other ShippingBatch the Orders belong to?

Comment: Sorry, I was doing something stupid there. Non-question